# Is it possible to setup a domain name in a wifi network?

Tags: java, networking

I have an android app where users share files on a Wifi network. One of this biggest problems is users have to type the Network IP Address of one another i.e 192.168.43.254. I was wondering if there is a way to to assign special domain name to these network IP's. Only within the network no internet. So when the user types `http://superapp` it will automatically open 192.168.43.254. 
Is this possible? if not what are some alternatives?

Comment: By default, you can access the device / computer in a network by its computer name.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run a DNS server within the network, add that hostname to the server, and configure the router's DHCP settings to tell clients to use the DNS server.

Comment: That sounds a bit complicated on a Android Hotspot system. Do you think android could go that far with just JAVA?

Comment: "That sounds a bit complicated on a Android Hotspot system" — It isn't.

Comment: "Do you think android could go that far with just JAVA?" — You might be able to implement Zeroconf/Bonjour for that. If you control the network, then setting up DNS would be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the network systems and wifi clients fall in the same IP range defined, say for example, from `192.168.1.1` through `192.168.1.255`, the net work app server can be accessed by its name over http and other protocols.
It is a general practice that the servers have a static IP though they are in a local network. If a network app server with IP `192.168.1.24` has a name *`droidapps`* then it can be accessed through `http://droidapps/path-to-apps?query=string&etc`. This should be working on WIFI enabled networks too if the client device too has an IP falling in the WIFI network's IP range.

Comment: How would I set the name for the http://droidapps ? Is there a specific code to it?

Comment: @Zakukashi: It is as simple as giving a name to your system in a network. Make sure that it also got assigned a static IP.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially modify the /etc/hosts file on every Android device, but then your devices need to be rooted.

The other option, as offered by @SLaks is to use a DNS server.  If it is on a local wifi router, most will work as DNS forwarders - ie: requests come to the router and the router submits the request to your ISP's DNS servers.  Some router software (such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) if memory serves) allows you to manually configure the DNS and add your own local server names to the router's DNS.